# Cors issue while accessing vercel serverless apis

Tags: reactjs, cors, serverless, vercel

I know this has been asked many times and answered. But none of the solutions worked for me. May be I am missing something simple :(

I have a reproducible example [here](https://github.com/saravmajestic/vercel-monorepo-cors)

I have

- a serverless function in `api` directory -> `api/serverless-example/handler`, created using vercel [example](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/quickstart).
- `web` directory for front end created by `create-react-app`

In the front end, `Learn react` button click triggers fetch api call to `serverless-example/handler` and this throws cors error. As suggested by [vercel team](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors) and many SO posts, i have tried both `vercel.json` and `allowCors` approach.

Now, it throws below error
`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5005/api/serverless-example/handler' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`.

I could not get past this error after many attempts. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: Yes, i have added `routes`config in vercel.json to include all routes and allow all methods. Updated my readme: https://github.com/saravmajestic/vercel-monorepo-cors/blob/main/README.md#workaround